# Processing Stripe Events with AWS Api Gateway vs AWS EventBridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, stripe-payments, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to set up a webhook endpoint in AWS to receive events from Stripe and a common flow seems to be:

API gateway -> Lambda that verifies request signature -> EventBridge -> Lambda for business logic

What's the point of using EventBridge here? Is it just to fan out the event to multiple consumers?

I currently have this set up with API gateway -> Lambda that verifies request + business logic and I just want to make sure that I'm not doing anything stupid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> and a common flow seems to be

Where are you seeing that?

> What's the point of using EventBridge here? Is it just to fan out the event to multiple consumers?

It really depends on whether you are building an event-driven architecture/flow or want a synchronous request/response flow. EventBridge provides a lot of value when you want to decouple your components using asynchronous event-driven flows. Furthermore, as you said, it can fan out to multiple targets with lots of integrations.

Btw: Have you seen this as a general discussion on using webhooks with EventBridge? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/sending-and-receiving-webhooks-on-aws-innovate-with-event-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

I see two main benefits of using EventBridge

1. Best practice - The Stripe [docs](https://docs.stripe.com/webhooks#acknowledge-events-immediately) say you should return a 2xx response as quickly as possible, and not to perform business logic that can delay this response / be time consuming. Verifying timestamp and signature and pushing the event to EventBridge is a quick affair, and then you can perform all your business logic from the EventBridge event
2. Future proofing your solution: Stripe is working on [pushing events directly to EventBridge](https://docs.stripe.com/event-destinations/eventbridge-beta), therefore skipping the need for a Webhook endpoint. I'm not in the beta so I cannot be sure, but I assume this should use IAM authentication and make the solution more secure, without the need to manage, roll and verify secrets.

The API Gateway seems redundant at first, and you could use a Lambda [Function URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html) instead, however with a function URL you can't limit inbound traffic to the authorised [Stripe IPs for webhooks](https://docs.stripe.com/ips?locale=en-GB#webhook-notifications), so you need to create a REST API with a Lambda integration and add a [Resource Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies.html) to the API.

It feels involved, but it's the safest way I could design it. The API Gateway and the ingress Lambda will go away once Stripe makes the Event Bridge integration available, and I will just respond to EventBridge